# Why won't my bot send messages to specific channels? Discord.py channel = bot.get_channel()

Tags: python, logging, discord, discord.py

**Discord Bot Not Sending Messages To Specified Channels**

Hello,

I'm creating a discord bot to log actions and send them to specific channels. Every time I run my code I get no errors but as soon as I type in the command/word used I get an error. I am just trying to log actions into another channel.

I haven't set this section up yet:

```
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$");
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$");

client = discord.Client()

# @client.event
# async def on_message(message):
#  id = client.get_guild(940403791092670464)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user} logged in now!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("$help"):
      response = print (f"@help command was used")
      await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} help stuff")
    elif "fudge" in message.content:
      await message.delete()
      response = print(f"You're not allowed to say those words {message.author.mention} Word Used: Fudge")
      await message.channel.send(f"You're not allowed to use those words {message.author}.")      
    elif "female dog" in message.content:
      channel = bot.get_channel(943040534165991485)
      await channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} Said the word female dog.")
      await message.channel.send(f"You're not allowed to say those words {message.author.mention}")
      await message.delete()
      response = print (f"Logging actions.")

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client.run(my_secret)
```

Here is my Err:

- Ignoring exception in on_message
- Traceback (most recent call last):

  - File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event await coro(*args, **kwargs)
- File "main.py", line 31, in on_message

  - await channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} Said the word Food.")
- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

**Anything helps!**

Comment: It's telling you that `channel` is None, which means that `bot.get_channel(943040534165991485)` must be returning None. That in turn means that it couldn't find the channel you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`fetch_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_channel) instead of `get_channel()`. In discord.py as a rule of thumb `fetch_something()` makes an API call while `get_something()` tries to get it from the cache.

Comment: Presumably in this case `fetch_channel` instead of `get_channel` (going by the code that isn't commented out)?

Comment: right yes i misread

Comment: Here is the err:
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/YorkBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 21, in on_message
    await channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} Said the word Bitch.")
TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine
/home/runner/Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py:350:

Comment: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.fetch_channel' was never awaited
  pass
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: I added fetch and that is what I got

Comment: as it says you need to await it
`channel = await bot.fetch_channel()`